# How do I get a list of senders with the corresponding sum of the karma they sent using Django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I am building an application that tracks karma that users give to each other.  I want to be able to build a leaderboard over a rolling 7-day period and a list of people who have given you the most karma over a rolling 7-day period.  I have come up the following model:

```
class KarmaAction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    karma = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.IntegerField()
```

First off, will the above model scale well as the number of users grows?  I am thinking of deleting any rows that are over 7 days old.  Secondly, I want to know how I can create a list of senders with the corresponding sum of the karma they have given the last few days.  Maybe it would look something like this:

```
supporters = {'User 1': 14, 'User 2': 12, 'User 3': 7, 'User 4': 2}
```

Is there any way to do this with the Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model seems reasonable to me; I don't really see another way to do it. You need all of the information in there to be able to fulfill your requirements, anyway. (Though `created_at` should probably be a `DateTimeField`?) If it ends up too slow, you'll probably just have to add aggressive caching.

You can do something like (untested, but I think it should work)

```
TIME_RANGE = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

KarmaAction.objects.filter(created_at__gte=now - TIME_RANGE) \
                   .filter(user=recepient_user) \
                   .values('sender') \
                   .annotate(total_sent=Sum('karma')) \
                   .order_by('total_sent')
```

which will [use the `values` to group by unique `sender`s and then sum their `karma` values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

I added the `order_by` to make sure that if there's a default ordering, [it gets cleared and doesn't interfere with the grouping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by). It also makes it easy to just get the top `n` senders of karma, though, by just adding e.g. `[:5]` to the end -- if you make it `-total_sent`, of course :).

I don't think the `filter` causes this problem, but I'm not positive without testing.